# get-config key change when upgrading to Linux2 in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux-2

I am upgrading my Elastic Beanstalk deploy to Linux2.  Several `.ebextensions` scripts are failing in the new deploy.  It appears that the usage for `get_config` has changed.

Old script variables:

```
EB_APP_USER=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user)
EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir)
EB_APP_PID_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_pid_dir)
EB_SCRIPT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k script_dir)
EB_SUPPORT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k support_dir)
```

I was able to find replacements for the first two at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms-scripts.html

New script variables:

```
EB_APP_USER=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config platformconfig -k AppUser)
EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config platformconfig -k AppDeployDir)
```

I am not able to find replacements for

- `app_pid_dir`
- `script_dir`
- `support_dir`

Anyone know what I should use?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a very satisfying answer, but it appears the remaining 3 are no longer supported.  I see others hardcoding those values as...

```
EB_APP_PID_DIR="/var/pids"
EB_SUPPORT_DIR="/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support"
```

In the rewrite of my scripts, I no longer needed the `script_dir`.

Post where I got these values was setting up sidekiq... https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=330819